# How to make xsd element extend another

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I have three different XML elements that have some common tags.

For e.g: Person has name, age, sex

Then I have Manager, Employee that would share the three fields the Person has plus Manager, Employee specific fields like managerNo, employeeNo etc.

Can I write something in xsd that would be like this:

**1. Declare Person element**

```
<xsd:element name="Person">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Person Request</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>              
                <xsd:element name="personname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" /> 
                <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />   
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

2. Use the above Person declaration and extend the Manager element:

***<xsd:element name="Manager" extends="tns:Person">  (just idea of what I am looking for)***

In effect, I am trying to mimic my schema definition as per Java (object oriented) inheritance like:

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   int age;

   // getters and setters for above variables go here
}
```

then do:

```
public class Manager extends Person {
   int managerNo;
   String departmentName;
}

public class Employee extends Person {
   int employeeNo;
   String designation;

 // getters/setters and other code goes here
}
```

I want to mimic this Java inheritance concept in the xsd such that I can declare one base element, and just extend that base element such that other child elements also inherit the properties of base element.

Comment: Sorry, the schema definition did not make it through my last post. Here is how i would define person <xsd:element name="Person">
  <xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:documentation>Person Request</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>    
    <xsd:element name="personName"           type="xsd:string"    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" /> 
    <xsd:element name="age"           type="xsd:integer"    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    <
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

```
<xs:extension base="AddressType">
```

in your Manager/Employye schema definition

```
<xs:complexType name="Manager">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Person"> 
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- Properties -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```