# How to extend element with identity constraint?

Tags: xml, xsd

In an Xml schema, I have defined an element `A` of a complex type with some child elements. That element `A` also requires uniqueness for the values of a specific attribute of its child elements.

Imagine it like this (and assume `local` to be declared as the namespace prefix for the target namespace of the schema):

```
<xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="childIdUniqueness">
        <xs:selector xpath="local:child"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Now, I need a very similar element `B` that behaves exactly like `A`, but has an additional `name` attribute.

**How can I extend my definition for element `A` to an element `B` with an additional attribute?**

Very similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499836/use-xml-schema-to-extend-an-element-rather-than-a-complextype) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672311/how-to-make-xsd-element-extend-another) point out that instead of extending the element, the complex type should be extended.

However, they do not address the issue that identity constraints such as `unique`, `key` or `keyref` are not contained within the complex type definition, but rather directly within the element definition (cf. Xml Schema references such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256101%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Hence, that would require me to copy all the identity constraints (as opposed to the above simplified sample code, my actual document has various identity constraints) to each derived element definition - a severe source of errors in the case of maintenance-based changes to the constraints.

What is more, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256146%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implies a uniqueness requirement for the value of the `name` attribute of the identity constraint. While the attribute description uses the obscure term *identity constraint set* to denote the uniqueness scope, the documentation for [`keyref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256478%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes it fairly clear that those names can be used to unambiguously identify an identity constraint within its schema, so the identity constraint name must be unique in the whole schema. Hence, even copying and pasting of the whole block of identity constraints will not do, I have to rename each identity constraint for each of its occurrences.

Is there any convention for dealing with this kind of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around it. Identity constraints are associated with elements; elements are not designed to participate in inheritance schemes. The only way to achieve reuse of definitions such as the one you want would be proprietary at this point. One way to do it could involve custom markup, some sort of syntactic sugar describing your reuse, and associated post processing steps to bring it back in line with the XSD spec, all part of an XSD release management process (what I refer to as XML schema refactoring, XSR).

Comment: Too bad that I am forced into code duplication, but thanks for confirming my suspicion. By the way, in my opinion, "elements are not designed to participant in inheritance schemes" is not primarily "the problem"; I'd rather identify "identity constraints are linked to elements rather than types" as "the problem". Not that it changes anything.